# How to parse a question mark as parameter in zsh/shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

The parameters `--help`, `-h` or `-?` are common for showing information about how to use a program/script.

So one may parse them like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# […]
case "$1" in
    '' ) # no parameters
        echo "something missing here"
    --help|-?|-h ) # show help message
        show_help
        exit
        ;;
    *)
        # do something else…
        ;;
esac
```

Passing `--help` and `-h` works. However when I pass `-?` to it, it fails with the error:

> zsh: no matches found: -?

Now even when using a simple if loop it fails:

```
if [ "$1" = "-?" ]; then
    show_help
    exit
fi
```

Note that passing `"-?"` or `'-?'` works, but that is silly and nobody does it.

I also could not reproduce this in bash, only in zsh.

Comment: I don't think `-?` is super common, I've never seen it. `-h` and `--help` should be enough.

Comment: Windows system uses `-?` or more commonly `/?`.

Comment: People use `"-?"` if that is what you need to work correctly.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your script.  When you type `./myscript -?` at an interactive zsh prompt, zsh is *not* invoking your script at all but emitting the error instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of a program with a `-?` help option is `less`. A long time ago, if you ran it with no arguments, it would say

```
Missing filename ("less -\?" for help)
```

Because `-?` by itself was fragile. In the Bourne/Korn/POSIX-compatible shells, it has different behavior depending on whether a file exists in the current directory with 2 characters in its name and `-` as the first character.

It doesn't say that any more, because `-\?` was a silly help option. Now it says

```
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)
```

(And surely it would have gone with `-h` if that hadn't been taken for some other purpose)

`less -\?` still displays the help, like it always did, but nobody is encouraged to use it.

Follow this example.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, question mark symbol resolves to return value of the last executed command. Anyway, guarding it with backslash "\" should prevent interpreting it as anything else.

```
#!/bin/zsh
# […]
case "$1" in
    '' ) # no parameters
        echo "something missing here"
    ;;
    --help|-\?|-h ) # show help message
        show_help
        exit
        ;;
    *)
        # do something else…
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the special parameter `?` (whose value is accessed with `$?`). The case expressions are patterns, so `-?` is a pattern that matches a literal `-` followed by any single character. The solution is correct, though; escaping `?` prevents it from acting as a metacharacter and allows one to match a literal question mark instead.

Comment: Indeed, escaping the -? there (in the script) does not help. As someone else told, zsh does not even execute the script, so one would have to escape the ? when running the command (`./script -\?`, maybe).